# ¿como crear estilos para un ID progresivo?

Tags: html5, css

Como puedo crear estilos para `ids` que se diferencian al final por un número? había visto algo como esto 
`"#1, #2 = id(+n)"` ,  pero no me funcionó

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Dices que tienes varios elementos, cada uno con el id `#{i}` donde `{i}` representa el índice de cada elemento y quieres darle estilos a cada uno? Si sabes a ciencia cierta la cantidad de elementos, puedes hacerlo en CSS como de costumbre o hacer un for si usas un procesador como LESS, SCSS o Stylus. También puedes crear un elemento `style`, agregarle los estilos como texto y agregarlo al `head` del documento.

Comment: gracias por responder, digamos que tengo un elemento así, #ejemplo, pero ese nombre se puede replicar muchas veces, y solo se diferencia por un numero "#ejemplo, #ejemplo2,"#ejemplo3...", quisiera saber que si no se sabe la cantidad de veces que este id crecerá, se pudiera hacer por css, un  estilo que aplique para las N cantidades que el id aparezca

Comment: ¿Todos tendrán las mismas reglas CSS? Porque si es así tan solo te basta usar un wildcard: `div[id^="ejemplo"]`. Lo anterior se traduce a: *"Aplica estos estilos a todo div que tenga un id que empiece con "ejemplo"*.

Comment: funcionó perfectamente, muy agradecido gustavo, sos un genio, solo tuve que cambiar la etiqueta div por button

Comment: Andrés, para mantener un orden he puesto mi comentario como respuesta para que sea aceptada y no quede como "no respondida". Cuando tengas un minuto la marcas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si todos los elementos tienen las mismas reglas CSS tan solo te basta usar un wildcard:

```
div[id^="ejemplo"]
```

Lo anterior se traduce a: "Aplica estos estilos a todo div que tenga un id que empiece con "ejemplo". De esta manera, puedes tener identificadores de tipo `ejemploN` y todos se verán afectados. Sin embargo, te recomiendo usar clases en su lugar.

Answer (score 0):

No conozco nada así (no quiero decirte que no existe porque no me sé el estándar de memoria). Lo habitual es añadir una clase común a todos los elementos que tienen ese id secuencial y usarla como selector.